# Sql Server 2008R2 enterprise with data encryption - backup and restore

Tags: sql-server-2008, encryption-symmetric

I have a DB on which I enabled symmetric encryption, to encrypt some columns.
I created a SP to enable encryption after I create the DB from script, as below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sys_EnableSymmetricEncryption]
AS
BEGIN
--If there is no master key, create one now. 
IF NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT * FROM sys.symmetric_keys WHERE symmetric_key_id = 101)
  CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY 
  PASSWORD = '9809u0ij989oih9o8yyo98yyo89uyp9p9'

CREATE CERTIFICATE My_Certificate
  WITH SUBJECT = 'My Database';

CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY My_Key_01
  WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256
  ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE My_Certificate;
END
```

So after I create db from script, I run this and then I can store data in encrypted columns
with

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Cards]
      ([CardNumber]
      ,[CardSecurityCode]
      ,[CardExpirationDate]
      ,[NameOnCard])
 VALUES
  (EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('My_Key_01'), @CardNumber) ,
  EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('My_Key_01'), @CardSecurityCode) ,
  EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('My_Key_01'), @CardExpirationDate) ,
  EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('My_Key_01'), @NameOnCard))
```

and retrieve data with

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY My_Key_01
   DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE My_Certificate;

SELECT [CardID]
      ,CONVERT(nvarchar, DecryptByKey([CardNumber])) as 'CardNumber'
      ,CONVERT(nvarchar, DecryptByKey([CardSecurityCode])) as 'CardSecurityCode'
      ,CONVERT(nvarchar, DecryptByKey([CardExpirationDate])) as 'CardExpirationDate'
      ,CONVERT(nvarchar, DecryptByKey([NameOnCard])) as 'NameOnCard'
    FROM [Cards]
```

All works well till I backup db and try to restore the backup on a different server
After I restore, when I try to run Select (as above) I get this error

`Please create a master key in the database or open the master key in the session before performing this operation.`

So I was trying to recreate the key with

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT * FROM sys.symmetric_keys WHERE symmetric_key_id = 101)
  CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY 
  PASSWORD = '9809u0ij989oih9o8yyo98yyo89uyp9p9'
```

But then on select In still get the same error.
If I try to run the first Sp shown above, to create master key, cert and symmetric key, I get error

`Msg 15581, Level 16, State 3, Procedure sys_EnableSymmetricEncryption, Line 11
Please create a master key in the database or open the master key in the session before performing this operation.
Msg 15282, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sys_EnableSymmetricEncryption, Line 14
A key with name 'OneTest_Key_01' or user defined unique identifier already exists or you do not have permissions to create`

Maybe I should try to delete the certificate and symmetric key before trying to create them, but I don't know where are they located.

Any idea how to handle this?

Thanks

PS if I restore in same server, even as different database, all works fine

Answer (score 1):

Try to run:

```
ALTER MASTER KEY REGENERATE WITH ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '9809u0ij989oih9o8yyo98yyo89uyp9p9';
```

Comment: When I run this I get the following error:<br> Msg 15329, Level 16, State 20, Line 1
The current master key cannot be decrypted. If this is a database master key, you should attempt to open it in the session before performing this operation. The FORCE option can be used to ignore this error and continue the operation but the data encrypted by the old master key will be lost.<br> Any idea?

Comment: unfortunetly no other ideas. I could only share what i found in web:  
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsecurity/thread/1962ea62-28d8-4331-af6e-a73e1a0d4bcc/  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017865/sql-server-2008-open-master-key-error-upon-physical-server-change-over